# GWT RequestBuilder fails with SSL connections (in tests). Why? Are there any workarounds?

Tags: gwt, ssl, junit, tdd

I try to connect to a (local) web service using the GWT RequestBuilder with a secure connection (SSL), but the connection isn't established... When I connect using a plain HTTP connection everything works fine.

### Some details

- everything works fine when I'm using my browser to view the pages,
- I use an auto signed SSL certificate on my local machine,
- the tests fail because the actual response code (responseCode) is not set,
- the tests work fine if I'm using a plain HTTP connection (no SSL).

### Code

```
package com.example.services;

import com.google.gwt.http.client.*;

import com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;

public class RequestBuilderTest extends GWTTestCase {
    private static String SERVER_URL = "https://127.0.0.1/api";
    private static final int ASSERT_DELAY_IN_MS = 15000;
    private static final int TEST_DURATION_IN_MS = 20000;
    private int statusCode;

    public void testGet() throws Exception {
        new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, SERVER_URL).sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable e) {
                fail(e.getMessage());
            }

            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
            }
        });

        delayTestFinish(TEST_DURATION_IN_MS);
        new Timer() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                assertEquals(Response.SC_OK, statusCode);
                finishTest();
            }
        }.schedule(ASSERT_DELAY_IN_MS);
    }

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "com.example.services.RequestBuilder";
    }
}
```

### Results

- test passes with SERVER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/api";
- test fails with SERVER_URL = "https://127.0.0.1/api";
  **This is the stack trace for junit:**

  junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Remote test failed at 127.0.0.1
   expected=200 actual=0

### Any ideas on what could be wrong and how can I make the tests work with SSL?

### EDIT

How can I force the tests to run in secure mode? I use eclipse... I tried setting some "Program arguments" in the "Run configurations" (for the junit tests), but they don't work... Here are the arguments:

```
-noserver -startupUrl https://192.168.8.147/com.example.services.RequestBuilderTest.JUnit/ -bindAddress 0.0.0.0
```

Is it better if I just deactivate the SSL on the server? These tests are meant to be launched on the continuous integration server and I wanted to test them using SSL.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running into a [same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?) problem.  Embedding a URL into the app like that is inherently unreliable.  Instead, use [`GWT.getModuleBaseUrl()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#getModuleBaseURL%28%29).

Comment: The web api is not implemented using GWT... and I tried to use your suggestion (GWT.getModuleBaseUrl()), but the URL I obtain doesn't point to the web api and as a result I obtain a 404 code when I try to connect.

Comment: The module base url is used to construct the url that you want to talk to.  The important parts of the module base url are the scheme, host and optional port.  It's those three components that determine an "origin".  In your case, since the target URL is `scheme://origin/api`, you'll need to trim down the base url to the third forward-slash.

Comment: Tried that: the resulting URL is for a plain http connection (not https) and I need https... (GWT.getModuleBaseURL() == "http://192.168.8.147:34790/com.example.services.RequestBuilder.JUnit/")

Comment: I'm voting for this answer because it's helpful, but it didn't solve my problem (so I won't accept it)...